# running java spark with intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I am new to `Spark`. I created a `maven` project and I fetched some `WordCount` to run it. I get this error message :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/api/java/function/FlatMapFunction
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2856)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1668)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52170', transport: 'socket'
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

the maven file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.spark.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-test</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

This error appears at runtime. How can I deal with that ? I have heard about `SPARK_CLASSPATH` but I don't know how to set it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`provided` scope means the JAR won't be packaged up with your application at build time - the jar will be provided by the target environment. Remove the line:

```
 <scope>provided</scope>
```

to use the default "compile" scope. Your app server probably doesnt provide the jar so the latter is required.

Comment: I can confirm that this will do the trick, I had to do the same thing a few weeks back to get the learning-spark-mini-example working.

Comment: thanks, it worked - could you provide some explanation

Comment: updated, also see the [reference doc](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)......